# REST API code for Domain and User creation in Nuxeo

Tags: nuxeo

I am very new to Nuxeo and due to customization I have to change some REST API functionalities for New Domain and User Creation in Nuxeo code base. But at time of debugging I am not able to find the proper classes or flow of the code. So, can anyone tell me the REST code flow or the java class names. Then I can do it by my self.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main REST API code lives in https://github.com/nuxeo/nuxeo/tree/master/nuxeo-features/rest-api

> I have to change some REST API functionalities for New Domain and User Creation in Nuxeo code base

This is not the way you are supposed to work with Nuxeo. You must not edit the Nuxeo code base but contribute some custom code with your own "bundles" and "extension points". Have you read [the Nuxeo Developer Documentation](http://doc.nuxeo.com/display/NXDOC/Developer+Documentation+Center)?

You should give a look at [NXDOC/How+to+Contribute+to+an+Extension](http://doc.nuxeo.com/display/NXDOC/How+to+Contribute+to+an+Extension) and [NXDOC/REST+API](http://doc.nuxeo.com/display/NXDOC/REST+API).

Comment: During creation of the Domain through REST API. The title tag is auto populated with . That means user can not provide custom name in domain during creation through the REST. So, is there any way to manage the domain title through the REST or any other extension way. It will be great if you can tell me where actually this code is written.

I am using /api/v1/path/ with POST to create new domain.